# How do I disable hints in Uncharted 2?

Tags: uncharted-2

I play Uncharted 2 in normal difficulty and the hints option is greyed out in the menu. Is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall, the option becomes available once the game has been completed at least once.

Answer (score 0):

Let Drake die once and restart checkpoint to remove the hint icon.